# owl carousel not working, the images are stacking one at the top

Tags: jquery, shopify, owl-carousel

Hi I am trying to create a custom carousel but it is not working properly. i have tried different methods. but it is now working, I have attached the image as well, the images are stacking at top of each other. The HTML code here belongs to shopify theme. in this code I want to show the recommended products n a slider format

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#news-slider").owlCarousel({
        items : 3,
        itemsDesktop:[1199,3],
        itemsDesktopSmall:[980,2],
        itemsMobile : [600,1],
        navigation:true,
        navigationText:["",""],
        pagination:true,
        autoPlay:true
    });
});
```

```css
.post-slide{
    background: #fff;
    margin: 20px 15px 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 14px 22px -9px #bbcbd8;
}
.post-slide .post-img{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: -12px 15px 8px 15px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
.post-slide .post-img img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transform: scale(1,1);
    transition:transform 0.2s linear;
}
.post-slide:hover .post-img img{
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
}
.post-slide .over-layer{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(6,190,244,0.75) 0%, rgba(45,112,253,0.6) 100%);
    transition:all 0.50s linear;
}
.post-slide:hover .over-layer{
    opacity:1;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.post-slide .over-layer i{
    position: relative;
    top:45%;
    text-align:center;
    display: block;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:25px;
}
.post-slide .post-content{
    background:#fff;
    padding: 2px 20px 40px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.post-slide .post-title a{
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#333;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.post-slide .post-title a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#3498db;
}
.post-slide .post-description{
    line-height:24px;
    color:#808080;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}
.post-slide .post-date{
    color:#a9a9a9;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.post-slide .post-date i{
    font-size:20px;
    margin-right:8px;
    color: #CFDACE;
}
.post-slide .read-more{
    padding: 7px 20px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #2196F3;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px -10px #1376c5;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.post-slide .read-more:hover{
    background: #3498db;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}
.owl-controls .owl-buttons{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-prev{
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top:-13%;
    left:15px;
    padding: 0 18px 0 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 3px 14px 25px -10px #92b4d0;
    transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next{
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top:-13%;
    right: 15px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 18px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: -3px 14px 25px -10px #92b4d0;
    transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-prev:after,
.owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next:after{
    content:"\f104";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    color: #333;
    font-size:30px;
}
.owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next:after{
    content:"\f105";
}
@media only screen and (max-width:1280px) {
    .post-slide .post-content{
        padding: 0px 15px 25px 15px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="product-recommendations" data-product-id="{{ product.id }}" data-limit="8">
 <div id="news-slider">
<div class="post-slide">
          <div class="post-img">
   
      {%- for product in recommendations.products -%}

     
          <img class="product__img" src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: '300x300' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt }}" />
          
       

      {%- endfor -%}
</div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Please some one can check where is my code wrong?[image]

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors.?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at Owl.setup (owl-carousal.js?v=12549767610488687638:582)
    at new Owl (owl-carousal.js?v=12549767610488687638:178)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (owl-carousal.js?v=12549767610488687638:1726)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:374)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.js:139)
    at n.fn.init.$.fn.owlCarousel (owl-carousal.js?v=12549767610488687638:1721)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.js?v=718976845532443896:2)
    at j (jquery.js:3094)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3206)

Comment: you need to init the carousel  `post-img` or need to change the structure and loop the div class name along with the loop `post-slide`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your html structure like this :

```
 <div id="news-slider" class="carousel-wrap">
    <div class="post-slide owl-carousel">
          {%- for product in recommendations.products -%}
          <div class="post-img">  
              <img class="product__img" src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: '300x300' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt }}" />
           </div>      
          {%- endfor -%}
    </div>
</div>
```

So , that each div has separate image inside it . Currently you are appending all images in one div.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".post-slide").owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 2],
    itemsMobile: [600, 1],
    navigation: true,
    navigationText: ["", ""],
    pagination: true,
    autoPlay: true
  });
});
```

```css
.post-slide {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 20px 15px 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0px 14px 22px -9px #bbcbd8;
}

.post-slide .post-img {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: -12px 15px 8px 15px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.post-slide .post-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

.post-slide:hover .post-img img {
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

.post-slide .over-layer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(6, 190, 244, 0.75) 0%, rgba(45, 112, 253, 0.6) 100%);
  transition: all 0.50s linear;
}

.post-slide:hover .over-layer {
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.post-slide .over-layer i {
  position: relative;
  top: 45%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.post-slide .post-content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2px 20px 40px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.post-slide .post-title a {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.post-slide .post-title a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3498db;
}

.post-slide .post-description {
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #808080;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.post-slide .post-date {
  color: #a9a9a9;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.post-slide .post-date i {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  color: #CFDACE;
}

.post-slide .read-more {
  padding: 7px 20px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px -10px #1376c5;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.post-slide .read-more:hover {
  background: #3498db;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.owl-controls .owl-buttons {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-prev {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -13%;
  left: 15px;
  padding: 0 18px 0 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 3px 14px 25px -10px #92b4d0;
  transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -13%;
  right: 15px;
  padding: 0 15px 0 18px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: -3px 14px 25px -10px #92b4d0;
  transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-prev:after,
.owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next:after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next:after {
  content: "\f105";
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1280px) {
  .post-slide .post-content {
    padding: 0px 15px 25px 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.3/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<div class="product-recommendations" data-product-id="{{ product.id }}" data-limit="8">
  <div id="news-slider" class="carousel-wrap">
    <div class="post-slide owl-carousel">
      <div class="post-img">
        <img class="product__img" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1f/65/30/1f65303066ef5e14cad11da3c6eeef0d.jpg" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt }}" />
      </div>
      <div class="post-img">

        <img class="product__img" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e8/c7/c4/e8c7c4d4e14a9e3b21faf3d7b37c5b03.jpg" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt }}" />
      </div>
      <div class="post-img">
        <img class="product__img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSrDI8z4T_iPTd3IzpxW_LPGeUPT3uVXwU4tA&usqp=CAU" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt }}" />
      </div>
      <div class="post-img">
        <img class="product__img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSrDI8z4T_iPTd3IzpxW_LPGeUPT3uVXwU4tA&usqp=CAU" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt }}" />
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```